# VHDL: several 'and' logic in 'if' fail

Tags: vhdl

```
Library IEEE;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;

ENTITY hazard_unit IS
 PORT(
  BranchD:in std_logic;
  RsD:in std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);
  RtD:in std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);
  RsE:in std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);
  RtE:in std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);
  WriteRegE:in std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);
  MemtoRegE:in std_logic;
  RegWriteE:in std_logic;
  WriteRegM:in std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);
  RegWriteM:in std_logic;
  WriteRegW:in std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);
  RegWriteW:in std_logic;

  StallF:out std_logic;
  StallD:out std_logic;
  ForwardAD:out std_logic;
  FlushE:out std_logic;
  ForwardAE:out std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
  ForwardBE:out std_logic_vector(1 downto 0)
 );
END hazard_unit;

ARCHITECTURE behavioral OF hazard_unit IS
  signal lwstall:std_logic:='0';
  signal branchstall:std_logic:='0';
  begin
  process(BranchD,RsD,RtD,RsE,RtE,WriteRegE,MemtoRegE,RegWriteE,WriteRegM,RegWriteM,WriteRegW,RegWriteW)
    begin
-----------Forwarding: former destination matches next source rs--------------------
    if    (RsE/="00000" and RsE=WriteRegM and RegWriteM) then    
         ForwardAE<="10";
    elsif ((RsE/="00000") and (RsE=WriteRegW) and RegWriteW) then
         ForwardAE<="01";
    else 
         ForwardAE<="00";
    end if;
-----------Forwarding: former destination matches next source rt---------------------
    if    ((RtE/="00000") and (RtE=WriteRegM) and RegWriteM) then    
         ForwardBE<="10";
    elsif ((RtE/="00000") and (RtE=WriteRegW) and RegWriteW) then
         ForwardBE<="01";
    else 
         ForwardBE<="00";
    end if;
----------LW Stall: lw instrucion's destination register RtE matches source register RsD, RtD---------------------
    lwstall<=((RsD=RtE) or (RtD=RtE)) and MemtoRegE;
----------Control hazard: Forwarding when result of ALU in the mem stage
    ForwardAD<=(RsD/=0) and (RsD=WriteRegM) and RegWriteM;
----------Control hazard: Stall when result of ALU in the exe stage
    branchstall<=(BranchD and RegWriteE and (WriteRegE=RsD or WriteRegE=RtD)) or (BranchD and MemtoRegM and (WriteRegM=RsD or WriteRegM=RtD));
    StallF<=lwstall or branchstall;
    StallD<=lwstall or branchstall;
    FlushE<=lwstall or branchstall;          
  end process;
end hazard_unit;
```

I tried to use several logic computations in an 'if', but they all fail. The error information is:

> No feasible entries for infix operator "and"

Can someone tell me what I did was wrong and how to fix it?
Thank you.

Comment: Of seven such errors the first four occurrences are caused because a condition (for the if statement) must evaluate to a boolean, there is no "and" operators defined with operands of std_logic and boolean returning a boolean.  The last three evaluate a boolean operand and should return a std_logic (std_ulogic) value, and likewise aren't defined.  The first four can be cured by the likes of changing a `RegWriteM` to `RegWriteM = '1'`. The remaining three require if statements (or conditional signal assignment, in which case you shouldn't use Synopsys packages (-2008)).

Comment: Be careful initialising signals:  `signal lwstall:std_logic:='0'; signal branchstall:std_logic:='0';`. The initial values will just be ignored by your logic synthesiser, so your gates will not match your simulation. Your design should not be relying of the initialisation of signals.

Comment: I also notice that you drive `lwstall` here: `lwstall<=((RsD=RtE) or (RtD=RtE)) and MemtoRegE;` and then sense it here: `StallF<=lwstall or branchstall;`. This will not do what you are expecting; the value of `lwstall` will not be updated by the time you sense it. It is the same situation for `branchstall`. You need to either add these two signals to the sensitivity list of the process, or (much better) move the lines that sense `lwstall` and `branchstall` into a separate process. Signals are not updated until the next _delta cycle_, which is after (all) the process(s) suspend(s).

Comment: @MatthewTaylor initial signal values are handled correctly by at least some FPGA synthesizer, e.g. Vivado, ISE and Quartus.

Comment: @Martin Zabel Thanks, I was aware of that, but coming from an IC background, relying on initialisation does seem rather scary. However, the initialised signals in this case are going to be synthesised as combinational logic; surely the initialisation of those is not going to be handled correctly?

Comment: @MatthewTaylor Sorry, I thought, you are talking about registers / latches. AFAIK, initial values for combinational signals are just ignored during synthesis.

Comment: @MatthewTaylor This is why I dislike signal initialization in general.  You have to be careful which signal you initialize, because they may or may not actually be initialized (depends on if the signal is registered).  It is easy to lose track.  And this leads to simulation/hardware mismatches.  Also, initialization hide issues of undriven signals.  I'd prefer to see a 'U' propagate in a simulation, and this has more value than a post-configuration initial value.